# Adapt existing markup for 1027x768 screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, screen-resolution

There is HTML page [http://s2.ralfgroup.com](http://s2.ralfgroup.com/) which is correctly displayed on *1280x1024*, but unfortunately goes beyond the screen on *1027x768*.

Actually the issue is in navigation (room image) on the main page. Is too large for screens with *1027x768* resolution.

Can anyone suggest a better way to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Please find below the screenshot how the page looks like on *1027x768* screens:
[image: How it looks like with 1024x768 screen resolution].

Comment: than wht do u want exactly..............

Answer (score 0):

Just define `min-width` in your body tag like mentioned below `CSS` :-

we are defining the `min-width` as per your parent `#block-views-categories-b-cat-menu` div width...

```
body {
    color: #E9E6D9;
    font: 17px/1.3em "Myriad Pro","Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;
    min-width: 1220px;
}
```

I hope this will work for you..........